# How to insert and display User and Address model using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I want to display both user info and address model in the same view.

These are my code structures:

In Data Access Layer, I have model classes:

**User.cs**:

```
public class User
{
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string RestaurantName { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryPhone { get; set; }    
}
```

**Location.cs**:

```
public class Location
{
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Line1 { get; set; }
            public string Line2 { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string ZipCode { get; set; }
            public User User { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have two separate repositories for user and address models which perform add and get all functions which is working perfectly fine.

Now, I want both of this model information should be displayed in the view at the same time.

How can I combine both in the same view. I'm unable to do it. I can do it, but the thing is both are displayed in separate views.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you create a ViewModel class and pass the entire class or a list of the ViewModel class?

Comment: Yeah, I can pass the VIew Model class. But my problem is I have two repositories like UserRepo and AddressRepo which does insertion of data separately. Sousing ViewModel, i'm able to combinely display the model. But the problem is, how to pass this viewmodal in two separate repositories to save the data in database.

Comment: Why don't you use an ajax post back to the controller and save data to the 2 repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ViewModel. Your ViewModel could look something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public User UserVm {get;set;}
    public Location LocationVm {get;set;}
}
```

Use the MyViewModel in your view. Your controller will accept a MyViewModel object.

You can then pass the LocationVm and UserVm objects from your viewModel to your repository.

Comment: So, how to pass it. When I try to do that I'm getting following exception:"cannot implicitly convert System.Collection.Generic.list<Projectname.Data.Models.User> to Projectname.Data.Models.User

Comment: I change my view model from User and Location to IEnumerable<User> and IEnumerable<Location>. So when I do it this error goes but i com eup with another issue in view. In view it says that **"IPrinciple does not contain a definition and no extension method accepting first argument of type Iprincipe in view in mvc"**

Comment: Fixed this issue by creating a separate viewmodel for index view and create view. Now, I'm able to gather the information. But having a problem in insering the data.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me that you wanted a list of users. I think your models are setup incorectly. Are you using entity framework? Is it a one-to-many relationship between User and Location? Or a one-to-one relationship? For one-to-many, you should add a Collection (not list) of Locations to the User. If its a one-to-one, wouldn't it make more sense for a User to have a Location than what you have now which is a Location that has a User?

Comment: For now, in my case I was thinking of having a one-one relationship between a user and location. Yes, I'm using Entity Framework. So, you mean to say I should have a location navigation property in User and may I know what should Location model have. Is it required to keep a navigation property of user in location?

Comment: Yes, Now I'm able to insert the data in the data base successfully. But, I'm unable to view it in the index view. May I know how to do it. When I use the above UserViewModel it gives me following error:**cannot implicitly convert System.Collection.Generic.list<Projectname.Data.Models.User> to Projectname.Data.Models.User**

Comment: I would not put a navigation property in Location, just put the navigation property in User. Update your question with your View code and the models you are now using?

Answer (score 1):

Add One more Property To your User Model like below

-- Model Section

```
public class User
{
public List<Location> location {get;set;}
}
```

-- Controller Section

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
List<Location> loc= new List<Location>() { new Location{ City = "one" }, new 
Location{ City = "two" } };

List<User> user= new List<User>() { new User{ FirstName = "A", location = 
loc }, new User{ FirstName = "B" } };

return View(user);
}
```

-- View Section

```
@model IEnumerable<YourSolutionName.Models.User>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)

      @{
          if (item.location != null) {  
        foreach(var i in item.location)
        {
            <h1>@i.City</h1>
        }
        }
    }
 }
```

This is one approach by using, we can use two different models on same view.

As for demo i added static values you can add dynamic using your context object.
it may help you. Thank You

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. Im able to bind the data in the viewmodel. But when I hit create, the viewmodel is not getting the data, it is getting null value. I dont understand what is going wrong

Comment: I mean you trying to say that, you need to Post(send) data to Controller.Is it right?

Comment: Yes, Now I'm able to insert the data in the data base successfully. But, I'm unable to view it in the index view. May I know how to do it. When I use the above UserViewModel it gives me following error:**"cannot implicitly convert System.Collection.Generic.list<Projectname.Data.Models.User> to Projectname.Data.Models.User"**